Issue with TypeORM Many-to-Many with Custom Fields via One-To-Many
I have a Format entity and a Format Detail entity which has variables that can be assigned to one or more Formats.  I also have a Format Detail Value entity which holds the value for a particular Format Detail assigned to a Format entity.
I setup the one to many relationships in Format and Format Detail that point to Format Detail Value entity.
Format Entity:
@OneToMany(() => FormatDetailValue, formatDetailValue => formatDetailValue.format)
    formatDetailValues: formatDetailValue[];

Format Detail Entity:
@OneToMany(() => FormatDetailValue, formatDetailValue => formatDetailValue.formatDetail)
    formatDetailValues: formatDetailValue[];

Format Detail Value Entity:
@ManyToOne(() => Format, Format => format.formatDetailValues)
    format: Format[];
    
@ManyToOne(() => FormatDetail, formatDetail => formatDetail.formatDetailValues)
    formatDetail: FormatDetail[];

Is it possible to setup relationships for Format and Format Details from the same table?
Format Detail Value Table:
format_detail_value (table) 
formatId (column)
formatDetailId (column)
formatDetailValue (column)

Basically I want the results structured as a Format has Format Details and Format Details have Format Detail Values.
Is this possible?  Or am I going about this in the completely wrong way?
